# I am currently in a provisionally accepted school, can it still lose accreditation? And will that will affect my practicing as a PA?

Tags: masters, medicine

Do I stay in this program, we are getting a new faculty & director. I already completed 5 months of the program & invested money. Do I transfer out to another PA program that is established? More time and money.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does the institution say? Are they currently accredited, seeking accreditation, or recently removed from accreditation? What, specifically, is required in your field?

Comment: We currently have provisional accreditation until the first cohort sits for the PANCE and takes the boards. If they do close down for some reason, we have to get dispersed to another program because of the standards ARC has in place

Comment: I am deciding whether I should just stay at the program I started with all though there is a lot of uncertainty with the new faculty & im scared I won’t get the quality education I need. Or to move to the new program, but having to restart, longer commute, and an extra year.

Comment: It sounds like you have the information you need to make a decision; we can't really make it for you.

Comment: At a minimum you need a sense of how committed the institution is to getting the program accredited. They are (or should be) well aware of the stakes not just for them but for their current and all future students .Normally there should be some evidence of starting up the program being a major, well funded initiative. Were most of the new faculty experienced hires from other accredited programs?